# run previous date script from crontab

Tags: unix, solaris

I made a small script to take take previous date as argument.  The script is running fine but when running this script from crontab it takes todays date

Script

```
Previous_day=`date --date="-1 days" +% Y% m% d`;
./some_script -date $Previous_day ;
```

Some_script is script which takes date as argument provided using -date

This is solaris box

Dont know why when running from crontab it runs with argument as today's date

Comment: What if you escape each one of the date arguments? `+\%Y\%m\%d`

Comment: is the entry in crontab under your user? Otherwise it could be an issue with a having a different timezone

Comment: When you type `which date`, does it say `/usr/bin/date` or something else? Maybe you're getting the GNU date when logged in but `/usr/bin/date`, which doesn't understand GNU extensions like `--date`, when running a cron job.

Comment: @user3744847 Remove the spaces and just do `previous_day=$(date --date="-1 days" "+\%Y\%m\%d")`

Comment: Are your two lines 2 crontab lines (second line is unaware of the first), or both part of the same script? Use #!/bin/sh as the first line when you want to test the crontab run.

Answer (score 0):

`%` is a [special character in Cron](https://serverfault.com/questions/274475/escaping-double-quotes-and-percent-signs-in-cron), so you should escape the date parameters:

```
Previous_day=`date --date="-1 days" +\%Y\%m\%d;
```

Comment: I tried following command in crontab but no output         echo `date --date="-1 days" + \% Y\% m\% d` > temp.log         no output in temp.log      . Please help what am I doing wrong